# React Native for Wearables (Companion mode)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

Can we build a **React Native wearable** Application?

Especially on **companion mode**.

Please provide any companion mode react native sample apps, if there are any.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently React Native not officially support Wearables but you can use [React native vanilla](https://github.com/pavjacko/renative)

Comment: Hi @Nooruddin is there any RN wearable applications in **existing market**  even if its with RN vanilla?

And are you sure that we cannot build companion mode application with RN now.

Answer (score 0):

## [react-native-wear-connectivity](https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity)

- Create a Wear OS app using react-native
- Connect two react-native apps (Wear OS and Android mobile app)
- **Both apps are written in react-native**

Video Preview: https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity/assets/24992535/415fab47-7d76-4c72-80b9-c0d19ec25a49

### Installation

```bash
yarn add react-native-wear-connectivity
```

### How to create a WearOS app using react-native

- Create a new react-native app using the same name as your Mobile app.
  It is important to use the same name because both apps need to share the same package name (AndroidManifest, build.gradle, the project files) and applicationId (build.gradle).

```bash
npx react-native@latest init YourMobileAppName
```

- Add the following line to the new project AndroidManifest (file ):

```xml
<!-- this file is located at android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

- Create a new emulator of type [WearOS Large round](https://gist.github.com/assets/24992535/f6cb9f84-dc50-492b-963d-6d9e9396f451).
- Pair the Android emulator with the Wear OS emulator. Follow this [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/connect-phone).
- Start the metro server on port 8082 with `yarn start --port=8082`
- Build the project with `yarn android`, open the [react native dev menu](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) and change the bundle location to `your-ip:8082` (for ex. `192.168.18.2:8082`).
- Repeat the same steps for the Android Phone Emulator and use a different port (for ex. 8081).
- **Important Note**: Before publishing to Google Play, make sure that both apps are signed using the same key (instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/signed-apk-android))

You can now build the app with `yarn android`. JS fast-refresh and the other metro functionalities work without problem.

### API Documentation

#### Send Messages

```js
import { sendMessage } from 'react-native-wear-connectivity';

sendMessage({ text: 'Hello watch!' });
```

#### Receive Messages

```js
import { watchEvents } from 'react-native-wear-connectivity';

const unsubscribe = watchEvents.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log('received message from watch', message);
});
```